# Convert bigint to bytea, but swap the byte order

Tags: postgresql, endianness, bytea

I have a PostgreSQL table that I want to alter a column from `bigint` to `bytea` byte to hold more data. I am thinking using the following sequence:

1. `alter table mytable add new_column`
2. `update mytable set new_column = int8send(old_column)`
3. `alter table drop old_column`
4. `alter table rename new_column to old_column`

The above sequence works, the only problem is that I want the byte sequence in the `bytea` to be *reversed*. For example, if a value in `old_column` is `0x1234567890abcdef`, the above sequence would generate `\0224Vx\220\253\315\357`, but I want it to be
`\357\315\253\220xV4\022`. Seems like the resulting `bytea` uses the big-endian order from originating `bigint`.

Is there an easy way to do that without writing a program? I was looking for a `swap64()` sort of function in PostgreSQL but failed to find one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure-SQL function I wrote to reverse the byte-order of a `bytea`-type value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_bytes_iter(bytes bytea, length int, midpoint int, index int)
RETURNS bytea AS
$$
  SELECT CASE WHEN index >= midpoint THEN bytes ELSE
    reverse_bytes_iter(
      set_byte(
        set_byte(bytes, index, get_byte(bytes, length-index)),
        length-index, get_byte(bytes, index)
      ),
      length, midpoint, index + 1
    )
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_bytes(bytes bytea) RETURNS bytea AS
'SELECT reverse_bytes_iter(bytes, octet_length(bytes)-1, octet_length(bytes)/2, 0)'
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

I just wrote it yesterday, so it's not particularly well-tested nor optimized, but it seems to work, at least on byte strings up to 1k in length.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to byte-swap without plpgsql code using regexp extractions on the hexadecimal representation.
Here's an example to swap a bigint constant, assuming `SET standard_conforming_strings to ON` (the default with PG 9.1)

```
select regexp_replace( lpad(to_hex(x'123456789abcd'::bigint),16,'0'),
 '(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)',
 '\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1');
```

It returns `cdab896745230100`. Then apply `decode(value, 'hex')` to convert that to a bytea.

The whole type conversion could actually be done in a single SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN old_column TYPE bytea
  USING decode(
    regexp_replace( lpad(to_hex(old_column), 16,'0'),
 '(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)',
 '\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1')
  , 'hex');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am playing with [`pageinspect` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pageinspect.html) now, and I was also curios how to change byte order of an existing bytea value, which pretty much matches your case.

I've come up with the following function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse(bytea) RETURNS bytea AS $reverse$
    SELECT string_agg(byte,''::bytea)
      FROM (
        SELECT substr($1,i,1) byte
          FROM generate_series(length($1),1,-1) i) s
$reverse$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

It's pretty straightforward and works similar to textual [`reverse()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function:

```sql
WITH v(val) AS (
    VALUES ('\xaabbccdd'::bytea),('\x0123456789abcd'::bytea)
)
SELECT val, reverse(val)
  FROM v;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This function](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/integer-to-little-endian-conversion-td1928406.html), while not exactly what you're looking for, should help you get on your way.

The source code from that function is reproduced verbatim below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utils.int_littleendian(v_number integer) 
  RETURNS bytea AS 
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
        v_textresult bytea; 
        v_temp int; 
        v_int int; 
        v_i int = 0; 
BEGIN 
        v_int = v_number; 
        v_textresult = '1234'; 
        WHILE(v_i < 4) LOOP 
                raise notice 'loop %',v_int; 
                v_temp := v_int%256; 
                v_int := v_int - v_temp; 
                v_int := v_int / 256; 
                SELECT set_byte(v_textresult,v_i,v_temp) INTO v_textresult; 
                v_i := v_i + 1; 
        END LOOP; 
        return v_textresult; 
END; 

$BODY$ 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE 
  COST 100;
```